# XY plot with multiple Y scales

Tags: r, plot

This is probably not a duplicate as I am not requesting how to plot 2 series in the same plot, but rather how to add 2 (interconnected) y scales on one XY series

Here is the frame

```
t <- data.frame(x=seq(0,1,0.01), y=exp(seq(0,1,0.01))*500, y2=exp(seq(0,1,0.01))*30)

head(t)
     x        y       y2
1 0.00 500.0000 30.00000
2 0.01 505.0251 30.30151
3 0.02 510.1007 30.60604
4 0.03 515.2273 30.91364
5 0.04 520.4054 31.22432
6 0.05 525.6355 31.53813
```

y and y2 are linearly interconnected. I would like to construct a plot with x, y (at left, side 2) and y2 (at right, side 4) so that each point on the plot has one x and 2 y coordinates.

base R only solutions please.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you want `y` and `y2` to correspond exactly (in terms of the scales)?

In that case, you can plot y vs x which draws an axis on the left hand side, and then draw an identical axis on the right hand side, *except* that you change the labels.

In base graphics:

```
# do first plot. Don't draw axis (we'll do it later)
plot(y~x,data=t,axes=F,ylab='y')
# draw y axis (see ?axis, 1=bottom, 2=left, 3=top, 4=right)
axis(2,pretty(range(t$y)))

# tell R to draw over the first plot
par(new=T)

# do second plot. 
plot(y2~x,data=t,axes=F,ylab="")
# draw second axis on the right
axis(4,pretty(range(t$y2)),ylab='y2')

# draw x axis on the bottom
axis(1,pretty(range(t$x)))

# draw the box if you want
box()
```

How this works:

1) plot y vs x. Doesn't draw the axes, because:
2) we draw on the axes. `axis(2,pretty(range(t$y)))`. `pretty` takes a start and end point, and generates suitable axis tick marks (usually multiples of 5 or 10)
3) `par(new=T)` : we tell R that the next plot it does should be drawn over the top of the current - don't wipe away what we've drawn so far!
4) we plot `y2` vs `x`. This resets the coordinate system to the `y2` coordinate system.
5) we draw the right hand axis. This works because since we've just plotted `y2` vs `x`, the coordinate system is for `y2` (and not for `y` as it was when we first started plotting).
6) draw on the x axis
7) draw the box around the plot (if you like).

#### Tweaks

You may notice that the plot is lop-sided - there's a lot more white space between the left hand side of the plot & the edge of the graphics device than there is on the right. That's because R wants to make space for the y label which is usually drawn on the left.

If you want to even it up, use `par(mar=c(top,left,bottom,right))`.

Looking at `?par`, we see the default is `c(5,4,4,2)+.1`.

So, add this snippet *to the front* of your code:

```
# get the current margins (top, left, bottom, right)
m <- par('mar')
# make sure the right margin is the same as the left.
m[4]<-m[2]
# set the new margins
par(mar=m)

# .... perform plotting as above.
```

Now you can see that there's equal space either side of the plot, so ti doesn't look lopsided any more. However, you may also notice that there is a y label on the left axis but not on the right.

It's a bit ugly - we have to add it in manually using `mtext` (which draws text on the plot):

```
mtext('y2',4,line=2)
```

The `'y2'` is the y axis label, the 4 means "draw on the right hand side of the plot", and `line=2` says "draw the label on line 2, starting from 0 at the axis and counting outwards".

#### Summary

```
# margin
m <- par('mar')
m[4] <- m[2]
par(mar=m)

# plotting
plot(y~x,data=t,axes=F,ylab='y')
axis(2,pretty(range(t$y)))
par(new=T)
plot(y2~x,data=t,axes=F,ylab="")
axis(4,pretty(range(t$y2)),ylab='y2')
axis(1,pretty(range(t$x)))
box()

# right-hand ylabel
mtext('y2',4,line=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Part2

```
  final ArrayList<Integer> posArrX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  final ArrayList<Integer> posX = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  final ArrayList<Integer> posArrY = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  final ArrayList<Integer> posY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  final Display display = new Display();
  final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
  shell.setSize(467, 264);

  //shell.setSize(xf, yf);

  shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
  // Create a canvas
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
  canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
     @Override
     public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        Canvas canvas = (Canvas) e.widget;
        int maxX = canvas.getSize().x - 50;
        int maxY = canvas.getSize().y - 20;
        e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        int h = 0;
        int pixelCount = 3;
        e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY, maxX + 50, maxY);

        e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY, 50, 0 + 0);

        e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY, convertXY(maxX), maxY - maxX);
        // System.out.println(maxY);
        // maxX = 1580;
        // suppose x = 400, y = 300 -- > 400 / 14 = .. X
        int maxLength = maxX;

        int maxWidth = maxY;

        int pointsOfX[] = {80, 150, 90, 100, 190, 170};
        int pointsOfY[] = {40, 120, 40, 80, 150, 140};

        // Arrays.sort(pointsOfX);

        // int maxLength = pointsOfX[3];

        int incX = maxLength / 5;
        int incY = maxWidth / 5;

        int px = 50;
        int py = 30;
        py = maxY - py;

        int counterx = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxX;) {

           x = x + 50;

           i = i + incX;

           e.gc.drawLine(50 + i, maxY, 50 + i, 0);
           e.gc.drawString("" + x, 30 + i, maxY + 3);
           // e.gc.drawString("80", 170, maxY - 20);

           posArrX.add(x);
           posX.add(50 + i);

        }
        // e.gc.drawString("" + x + 50, maxX - 10, maxY + 3);

        int countery = 0;
        for (int i = 10; i < maxY - 20;) {
           y = y + 50;

           i = i + incY;

           e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY - i, maxX + 50, maxY - i);
           e.gc.drawString("" + y, 30, (maxY - i) + 10);
           countery++;
           posArrY.add(y);
           posY.add(maxY - i);

        }
        System.out.println(posArrX.get(0) + " hier xxxxx" + posX.get(0));

        //int pointsOfX[] = { 100, 200, 50, 150 };
        //int pointsOfY[] = { 80, 150, 250, 179 };

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsOfX.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < posArrX.size(); j++) {

              if (pointsOfX[i] <= posArrX.get(j)) {
                 System.out.println(posX.get(j) + "hier   = "
                          + posArrX.get(j));
                 for (int k = 0; k < posArrY.size(); k++) {
                    if (pointsOfY[i] < posArrY.get(k)) {

                       for (int L = 0; L < pixelCount; L++) {
                          for (int M = 0; M < pixelCount; M++) {
                             e.gc.drawPoint((posX.get(j) - 10)
                                      + M, (posY.get(k) + 10) + L);

                             // e.gc.drawPoint(px + j, py + i);

                          }
                       }
                       break;
                    }
                 }

                 break;

              }
           }
        }
        e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY, convertXY(maxX), maxY - maxX);

        posArrX.clear();
        posX.clear();

        posArrY.clear();
        posY.clear();

     }

  });

  shell.open();
  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
     if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
```

}
}